# dataframe is collapsed to a vector when given to function

Tags: r, dataframe, mapply, custom-function

I am trying to make use of the content of a dataframe in a function, here is a simplified example of my problem.

```
df <- data.frame(v1=1:10,v2=23:32)
df2 <- data.frame(v1=1:3,v2=3:5)

fxm <- function(x,y,q)
{
    return(cbind(q[q[,2]==x,],y))
}

mapply(fxm,df[,1],df[,2],q=df2)
```

> Error in q[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions

if I add a print statement:
    df <- data.frame(v1=1:10,v2=23:32)
    df2 <- data.frame(v1=1:3,v2=3:5)

```
fxm <- function(x,y,q)
{
    print(q)
    return(cbind(q[q[,2]==x,],y))
}

mapply(fxm,df[,1],df[,2],q=df2)
```

I get:

> [1] 1 2 3
>
> Error in q[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions

The data frame is converted to a vector of its first column for some reason. How can I stop this from happening, and have the whole dataframe accessible to my function?

I am trying to select a subset of the dataframe and returning it based on the other two parameters of the function, which is why I need the whole dataframe to be passed to the function.

Comment: What is the result you are looking to get? - As a first attempt try and remove the comma from `q` indexing in your function( i.e. `return(x+y+q[2])`)

Comment: I think I oversimplified my problem, I have edited it which will hopefully clear it up a bit. 

removing the comma from the q index would just select the 2nd element from the vector that came from the first column of my dataframe as a result of some default behaviour I don't understand, which  does not help me as I need access to the nth column of a dataframe for a comparison operation, and the rest of the data frame to return it.

Comment: What is your expected output from this function?

Comment: `data[, singe_column]` will return a vector. You can use `data[single_column]` or `data[, single_column, drop = FALSE]` to return a data frame. This is essentially [R-FAQ 7.5](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-my-matrices-lose-dimensions_003f)

Comment: That said, it also seems like you are doing nothing to ensure that the vectors you bind together have the same length, so that could cause problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the whole thing `q = df2` passed to the `fxm` function you define, am I right?

The problem is that in your code `mapply` will extract elements from `q = df2` as some additional parameters just same as extracting elements from `df[,1]` and `df[,2]`. You need to set `MoreArgs` parameter for `mapply` to pass the whole thing to the function like this:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=1:10,v2=23:32)
df2 <- data.frame(v1=1:3,v2=3:5)

fxm <- function(x,y,q)
{
    print(q)
    return(cbind(q[q[,2]==x,],y))
}

mapply(fxm,df[,1],df[,2], MoreArgs = list(q=df2))
```

This still doesn't work for me and there is some error elsewhere. From the printing result you can see the whole `data.frame` prints out, which solves your original problem.